# Prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $x \geq 3$, if $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $3^x - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

**Prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 3$, if $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $3^x -2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.**

I was trying to use induction:

Base case $(x = 3)$:
If $3 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $3^3 - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ holds

Inductive step ($n > 3$):
Assume that for every $y$ from $3$ to $x-1$, if $y \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $3^y - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

But I'm stuck in the inductive step, so not sure if induction is the right way to prove this claim.

Comment: Note: when you write "x=y (mod n)", that's incorrect. You mean that x is congruent to y, (mod n). The equal- and congruency-signs look similar, but the difference is important.

Comment: Because we are only looking at $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, the induction step goes from $x$ to $x+4$ (or from $x-4$ to $x$, if you prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom's answer shows how to
get the result without induction.

To get it by induction,
suppose that
$3^{4n+3} \equiv 2 (\mod 5)$.

This is true for
$n=0$.

You want to show that
$3^{4(n+1)+3} \equiv 2 (\mod 5)$.

$\begin{align}
3^{4(n+1)+3}
&=3^{4n+4+3}\\
&=3^{4n+3}3^4\\
&=3^{4n+3}81\\
&\equiv 3^{4n+3} (\mod 5)\\
&\equiv 2(\mod 5)\\
\end{align}
$

since
$81 \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$.

More generally,
since $3^4 = 81 \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$,
if $0 \le k < 4$,
$3^{4n+k} \equiv
3^k (\mod 5)$
for all $n$
by exactly the same
induction proof.

Even more generally,
if $a^b  \equiv 1 (\mod c)$,
if $0 \le k < c$,
then
$a^{bn+k} \equiv
a^k (\mod c)$
for all $n$
by exactly the same
induction proof.

Of course this can be
directly proved
as in Tom's proof by,
computing $(\mod c)$,
$a^{bn+k} 
\equiv a^{bn}a^k
\equiv (a^b)^na^k
\equiv (1)^na^k
\equiv a^k
$

Comment: But how do you know that $n+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is true?

Comment: You don't. Where is this assumed?

Answer (score 1):

If $x \geq 3$ and $x \cong 3$ $\mod 4$ then $x = 4q + 3$ for some integer $q \geq 0$. So, now $3^x = 3^{4q+3} = 27(3^4)^q = 27(81)^q$. Now, what is $27(81)^q$ congruent to $\mod 5$?

Comment: Sorry, it should say $27(81)^q - 2$ congruent to $\mod 5$. But are you suggesting that induction is not the right way to prove this proposition?

Comment: That's exactly what he's suggesting.

Comment: I'm not saying that induction has no place in this problem. But, I imagine that you have already seen that $(ab)\mod k \cong (a \mod k)(b \mod k)$ and from there used an induction to prove that $(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n) \mod k \cong (a_1 \mod k)(a_2 \mod k) \cdots (a_n \mod k)$. Once you have shown this general result, then you can do this problem directly (without another induction) by looking at $27(81)^q$ (which if you can show is congruent to $2 \mod 5$ is equivalent to showing $27(81)^q-2$ is congruent to $0 \mod 5$).